# Dialogues do not close in Vala

Tags: gnome, vala, gtk3

For some reason, dialogue boxes don't close in my program, even though shown by standard `dialog.run()` call. They show and they return codes, but buttons don't close them. Here's some code with which this happens:

```
//Inside constructor for my window class
load_dlg = new FileChooserDialog("Select file to open...", this,
FileChooserAction.OPEN,
Gtk.Stock.CANCEL, ResponseType.CANCEL,
Gtk.Stock.OPEN, ResponseType.ACCEPT, null);
//...
//Inside an event handler method
if(load_dlg.run() == Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT){
    image_backend = new Pixbuf.from_file(load_dlg.get_filename()); // This works, and it's in a try clause.
```

And everything is fine except that the dialogue just won't close after returning a code. Same with `AboutDialog`. Everything works just fine in Python, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `load_dlg.hide()` after `load_dlg.run()` has returned.

Comment: Yep, it worked. I'm kind of baffled by this behaviour, though, as in most other cases `dialog.run()` both returned the code _and_ closed the dialogue window (Python, C++, C,...).

Comment: Not in C: After `gtk_dialog_run()` returns, you are responsible for hiding or destroying the dialog if you wish to do so. --[GtkDialog](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-run)

Comment: Really? I was sure `gtk_dialog_run()` handled hiding the dialogue boxes in C as well. But it actually explains things, since Vala sits on top of C. Thanks!

Comment: Really. Even in Python I have to call `dialog.hide()` after `dialog.run()` otherwise it sticks around.